# English version of Manin's "Correspondences, motifs and monoidal transformations "

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi everyone, I want to find a classical paper "Correspondences, motifs and monoidal transformations " by Manin. But I only found the Russian version. Dose this paper exist a english version? and where I could get it ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: From Math Reviews: This article has appeared in English translation [Math. USSR-Sb. 6 (1968), 439--470].

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5734/6/4/A01 - yours for only US$60!

Comment: here is a scan: agssp.torsor.org/documents/manin.pdf